# Using `ar` function in R to fit a AR(p) with predetermined exact order p.

Tags: r, time-series, autoregressive

I am playing with R's sunspot data and I have $X$ as the yearly sum of sunspots(hence $X$ is a vector of length 235).

I want to fit different AR models with different orders, $p = 1, 2, ..., 20$.
I use the `ar` function in R. According to **R documentation** if input `AIC = FALSE`, then `AR` fits the an AR model with order as input `order.max`.
But no matter which method I use (`"yw", "mle", "yule-walker"`), I can't fit to  exact order i want?

An example:

```
> ar(X, order.max = 20, AIC = FALSE )

Call:
ar(x = X, order.max = 20, AIC = FALSE)

Coefficients:
      1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8        9  

 1.2187  -0.4644  -0.1339   0.1351  -0.1133   0.0730  -0.0450   0.0189   0.1604  

Order selected 9  sigma^2 estimated as  38050
```

In this case I want an AR model (no matter how bad the fit is) of order 20 but it returns a model of order 9.
**How do force this `AR`to give the exact number of order I want?**  or **What other function could solve my problem?**

Quote from R documentation: *AIC: Logical flag. If `TRUE` then the Akaike Information Criterion is used to choose the order of the autoregressive model. If `FALSE`, the model of order `order.max` is fitted.*

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.4.1/topics/ar

Comment: Perhaps an R site would be a better place for this?

Answer (score 5):

Capitalization matters. The parameter is called `aic`, not `AIC`. (Yes, this is confusing.) Compare

```
> ar(rnorm(100),order.max=10,aic=FALSE)

Call:
ar(x = rnorm(100), aic = FALSE, order.max = 10)

Coefficients:
      1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8        9       10  
-0.1336  -0.2134  -0.2048  -0.1155  -0.1094  -0.1778  -0.0832  -0.2873   0.0274  -0.1503  

Order selected 10  sigma^2 estimated as  0.9316
```

to

```
> ar(rnorm(100),order.max=10,AIC=FALSE)

Call:
ar(x = rnorm(100), order.max = 10, AIC = FALSE)

Coefficients:
      1        2        3        4        5  
-0.0506   0.0128   0.0613  -0.2425  -0.2732  

Order selected 5  sigma^2 estimated as  0.8332
```